# Center align div inside div?

Tags: css

How do I center align 3 floating divs inside each other centered on page ?

```
<div style="width:100%">
     <div style="width:90%">
           <div style="width:80%">
                //Content
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center DIV in DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `margin: auto` in CSS.

```
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 500px; margin: auto;">
     <div style="background-color: green; height: 100px; width: 300px; margin: auto;">
           <div style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: auto;">
                //Content
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but my divs have width in percentages like 100%,80%, 50 % .

Comment: just change pixel widths to percents, it will still work. The important thing in my code is `margin: auto`.

Comment: What is the 0 in margin for ?

Comment: margin has a shorthand: `margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left]`. `margin: 0 auto` is a shortened version which means `margin: 0 auto 0 auto`, so left and right margin is auto, while top and bottom margin is 0.

Comment: Works out great.
Thank you. Wayne

Answer (score 3):

If the element you're centering has a specified width, you can center it with `margin: 0 auto`