# Vertically center two elements within a div

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to vertically center two `<p>` elements.

I followed the tutorial at [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) but still the elements get placed above the div, below the div, top-aligned within the div.

I would try something else but most of the questions here just point back to that tutorial.

This snippet is for a banner that is on the top of a web page.

```css
.banner {
  width: 980px;
  height: 69px;
  background-image: url(../images/nav-bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* color: #ffffff; */
}

.bannerleft {
  float: left;
  width: 420px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 652px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.bannerright {
  float: right;
  width: 555px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.bannerrightinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 52px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="bannerleft">
    I am vertically centered
  </div>
  <div class="bannerright">
    <div class="bannerrightinner">
      <p>I should be</p>
      <p>vertically centered</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following:
display:table; to bannerRight

display:table-cell; and
vertical-align:middle; to bannerrightinner

I have not tried this, please give me feedback if it does not work. ;)

EDIT: forgot to mention: take 'float' and 'position' properties off

Comment: display:table is because vertical-align:middle only works on tables. You're welcome, I'm glad you did find the answer.

Answer (score 42):

#### How to Center Elements Vertically, Horizontally or Both

Here are two ways to center divs within divs.

One way uses CSS **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)** and the other way uses CSS **table and positioning** properties.

In both cases, the height of the centered divs can be variable, undefined, unknown, whatever. The height of the centered divs doesn't matter.

[image]

Here's the HTML for both:

```
<div id="container">   

    <div class="box" id="bluebox">
        <p>DIV #1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="redbox">
        <p>DIV #2</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

#### CSS Flexbox Method

```
#container {
    display: flex;              /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;     /* stack flex items vertically */
    justify-content: center;    /* center items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;        /* center items horizontally, in this case */
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt8bct5x/)

The two child elements (`.box`) are aligned vertically with `flex-direction: column`. For horizontal alignment, switch the `flex-direction` to `row` (or simply remove the rule as `flex-direction: row` is the default setting). The items will remain centered vertically and horizontally ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt8bct5x/91/)).

---

#### CSS Table and Positioning Method

```
body {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 7px auto;   
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt8bct5x/1/)

---

***Which method to use...***

If you're not sure which method to use, I would recommend flexbox for these reasons:

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. as noted above, centering is simple and easy ([see another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276))
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

***Browser support***

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).