# center divs inside divs vertically

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have 2 divs inside a container div like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="title">A</div>
    <div id="text">Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... Some text... </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the title, I'm trying to align the divs `title` and `text` vertically and next to each other inside the parent div `wrapper`. So far my css is this:

```
#wrapper
{       
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}

#title
{
    background: url('path_to_purple_background') no-repeat;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    color:white;    
}

#text {
    width: 700px;
}

#title, #text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

But what I get so far is that the letter `A` is not centered inside my div `title` (it is instead positioned at the top-left corner of the div). Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought,  but there is a `text-align:center` property that you can add into `#title` as well as `line-height:HEIGHT OF #TITLE;` you can add. This will align the `A` to the center of the circle, as well as set the line-height of the `A` to match the height of the circle container, thus vertically aligning it to the middle.

Comment: It works, but not in IE7, how can I make this work for IE7 also?

Comment: I'm assuming the lineHeight doesn't work, so you can use `<!--[if IE 7]>
           <style type="text/css">line-height: IE LINE HEIGHT HERE;</style>
       <![endif]-->`. This will apply a different line height for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SYfPL/)? I set the `display` property of `#test, #title` to `table-cell`.

Comment: The div `title` grows as the text in the div `text` grows, I don't want that.

Comment: Just noticed that, `inline-block` seems like a better solution for that. I'll try to find out why the `vertical-align` isn't effective.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `vertical-align` gets mistaken very often.

From the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align):

> The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a
>   line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

So if you have got an inline image in an paragraph, you can use it to vertical-align it within a rule of text.

In your case, if you need to vertical-align only one rule, you can use the old `line-height` trick:

```
#title {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```