# Vertically align center inside div element

Tags: css, html

My text have only 1 line and my picture will fit the container height. 
I want text and picture to align center vertically. 
I try margin top text class with negative value and position relative but nothing work what I really want.

[jsfriddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCAwm/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="friend_select">
        <div class="Friend">
            <img class="Picture" src="http://graph.facebook.com/harell/picture?type=square&width=80&height=80" />
            <span class="Name">First Name Last Name 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Friend">
            <img class="Picture" src="http://graph.facebook.com/harell/picture?type=square&width=80&height=80" />
            <span class="Name">First Name Last Name 2</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#friend_select{ padding: 5px; width: 400px; height: 500px; }
.Friend{ height: 80px; } 
.Friend .Name{ line-height: 80px; }
.Friend .Picture{ line-height: 80px; width: 80px; height: 80px; }
```

​

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wCAwm/2/ ?

Comment: ah just like this what a big neglect of me.

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center an element within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this fix:

```
.Friend .Name{ line-height: 80px; vertical-align:top; }
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/WNT7U/

Works in latest Firefox, Chrome and IE down to IE8. For IE7, apply this hack:

```
.Friend .Name { *zoom:1; }
```