# How to center a paragraph element inside a div container?

Tags: html, css, text, centering

I want my paragraph element to be at the center of a container div, as in perfectly centered -- the top, bottom, left and right margins split the spaces equally.

How can I achieve that?

```js
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I want this paragraph to be at the center, but it's not.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That I know of, you can only vertically center with table cells, JavaScript, or if you know the height of the element to be vertically centered ahead of time

Comment: @ExplosionPills is right. You'd need to know the height of the <p> tag. If you did, you could do something like this in your stylesheet: p { width: 200px; height: 10px; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -100px 0 0 -5px; }

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center an element within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You dont need absolute positioning
Use

```
p {
 text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;

}
```

And adjust at will...

**If text exceeds width and goes more than one line**

In that case the adjust you can do is to include the display property in your rules as follows;

*(I added a background for a better view of the example)*

```
div
{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;  
  display: table; 
  background:#ccddcc;  
}


p {
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;   
}
```

Play with it in this [JBin](http://jsbin.com/amirot/1/edit)

[image]

Comment: I didn't vote you down but this will fail if the text is longer than a single line.

Comment: Alright, I followed your advice and with a little tweaking it worked.

div
{
width:300px;
background-color:yellow;
padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px
}

p
{
  text-align:center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

Like that, it centers perfectly, but Is this the right way to do?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thats why he must then adjust at will. As for example wraping the paragraph etc. I was adressing the center issue.

Comment: You are welcome @Johnsy Omniscient. Unfortunately , in spite of me trying to help, I recived a down vote. Who knows why!!. Have a good day

Comment: Johnsy & @insertusernamehere, Last but not least. I extended my answer to cover the case of a longer text that the width available. I included a jsBin to play with. See you! :)

Comment: Ok ok, thanks again, now I've read this thread again and I know what to do next time I encounter this problem. ^_^

Comment: This is elegant and the winner answer

Answer (score 21):

To get left/right centering, then applying `text-align: center` to the `div` and `margin: auto` to the `p`.

For vertical positioning you should make sure you understand the different ways of doing so, this is a commonly asked problem: [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: margin: auto did the thing! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

♣you should do these steps :

1. the **mother Element** should be **positioned**(for EXP you can give it position:relative;)
2. the **child Element** should have positioned "**Absolute**" and values should set like this: top:0;buttom:0;right:0;left:0; (to be middle vertically)
3. for the **child Element** you should set "**margin : auto**" (to be middle vertically)
4. the **child and mother Element** should **have "height"and"width"** value
5. for **mother Element** => **text-align:center** (to be middle horizontally)

♣♣simply here is the summery of those 5 steps:

```
.mother_Element {
    position : relative;
    height : 20%;
    width : 5%;
    text-align : center
    }
.child_Element {
    height : 1.2 em;
    width : 5%;
    margin : auto;
    position : absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how I do it:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.paragraph {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="paragraph">I want this paragraph to be at the center, but it's not.</p>
</div>
```

you can add `text-align: center;` to the paragraph if you want text alignment to be center

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `text-align: center` to your `<div>`

In your case also remove both styles that you added to your `<p>`.

Check out the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/76uGE/3/

Good Luck

Comment: It was NOT vertically middled. I updated your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9Mk64/

Comment: Yea. I thought he's only asking for a horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

**Centered and middled content ?**

Do it this way :

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">Table once ruled centering</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I [fiddled it here](http://jsfiddle.net/MLxNV/)

**Ha, let me guess .. you want DIVs ..**

just make your first outter DIV behave like a table-cell then style it with vertical align:middle;

```
<div>
    <p>I want this paragraph to be at the center, but I can't.</p>
</div>

div {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:aqua;
    text-align:center;
    /*  there it is */
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/9Mk64/](http://jsfiddle.net/9Mk64/)

Comment: Why provide a solution using `<table>` at all when you know it's wrong?

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not for layout purposes.  A table containing a single cell in a single row is most definitely not representing tabular data.

Comment: Oh, symantic point of view, you're right. Centering and middleing, i'm right.

Answer (score 0):

on the p element, add 3 styling rules.

```
.myCenteredPElement{
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine for all major browsers, except IE. So keep that in mind.

In this example, basicaly I use positioning, horizontal and vertical transform for the UI element to center it.

```css
        .container {
            /* set the the position to relative */
            position: relative;
            width: 30rem;
            height: 20rem;
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }


        .paragh {
            /* set the the position to absolute */
            position: absolute;
            /* set the the position of the helper container into the middle of its space */
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            font-size: 30px;
            /* make sure padding and margin do not disturb the calculation of the center point */
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            /* using centers for the transform */
            transform-origin: center center;
            /* calling calc() function for the calculation to move left and up the element from the center point */
            transform: translateX(calc((100% / 2) * (-1))) translateY(calc((100% / 2) * (-1)));
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="paragh">Text</p>
</div>
```

I hope this help.