# How do I center 1 paragraph element in 1 div element?

Tags: css

I'm following this [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121343/how-to-center-a-p-element-inside-a-div-container) and the p element is not centering.

Basically I gave the containing div a width and height and then set text align attribute to center for the p element inside the div.  No go.

What can I try next?

The containing div is `id=Y1aa`

I only  need horizontal centering for now.

```css
#Y1 {
  z-index: 4000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .95;
}
#Y1a {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: dotted 1px #000000;
  border-right: dotted 1px #000000;
}
#Y1aa {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}
.top {
  color: #000000;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='Y1'>
  <div id='Y1a'>

    <div id="Y1aa">
      <p class="top">Foo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Unknow - What do you mean, is it centered in your browser?

Comment: center vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @cadegalt It's better to post the code then to make us go to the site and use web inspector

Comment: so, you can use `text-align: center` or what do you mean?

Comment: @cadegalt Change `display:inline` to `display:block` in your `top` class

Comment: @cadegalt oh. sorry it's `position: absolute`. You can add to you `.top` class this: `display: block; text-align: center;`.

Comment: it's centering in the fiddle with text-align center he just needs to close the other div tags  http://jsfiddle.net/o7dLmv7w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display:inline` to `display:block` in your `top` class, or delete the `display` style all together.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from your `.top` class this: `display: inline;`.

```css
#Y1 {
  z-index: 4000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .95;
}
#Y1a {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: dotted 1px #000000;
  border-right: dotted 1px #000000;
}
#Y1aa {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}
.top {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='Y1'>
  <div id='Y1a'>

    <div id="Y1aa">
      <p class="top">O: 832-418-9180 M: 281-923-3638 S: 281-968-0727</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can just remove `display:inline` rather than adding `display:block`. `<p>` elements typically [default to block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html).

Comment: @showdev oh, really:) It this case yes. But in first edition of question - I get code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121343/how-to-center-a-p-element-inside-a-div-container) question and subconsciously work with this code:)

Comment: @showdev I'm a little bit confused - because in first example he has ` position: absolute` and there we should add `display: block;`

Comment: It doesn't hurt to add it, I just don't think it's necessary because the default display mode for `<p>` elements is `block`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could add `text-align: center` to `#Y1aa` if you need to keep the `p` as an `inline` element.

```css
#Y1 {
  z-index: 4000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .95;
}
#Y1a {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: dotted 1px #000000;
  border-right: dotted 1px #000000;
}
#Y1aa {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top {
  color: #000000;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='Y1'>
  <div id='Y1a'>
    <div id="Y1aa">
      <p class="top">O: 832-418-9180 M: 281-923-3638 S: 281-968-0727</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To center a paragraph inside a div you will have to use the margin attribute in the CSS style for the paragraph

In this example i am centering the first paragraph inside the div with class 'wrap'

```css
 .wrap p:first-child {
     text-align:center;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
     <p>Some p tag</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: his `<p>` is `position: absolute`

Comment: And why should it? The question clearly reads: How do I center 1 paragraph element in 1 div element? This is a perfectly good answer to that question. Now the OP can apply this method to the code the OP have.