# Centering text in a <div></div> prevents movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to center both **horizontally and vertically** a `<p></p>` that could consist of **one or more lines**, in a `<div></div>`. Only the parent's width and height are known. Note: I refer to the div as parent, and the p as child.

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121343/how-to-center-a-p-element-inside-a-div-container) and on other sites, that in order to do vertical centering, the best way would be by using `display: table` on the parent element and `display: table-cell` combined with `vertical-align: middle` on the child.

However, I need the div's style.top and style.left to be overwritten later by some javascript, to make it move. By using the table trick, it somehow prevents me from moving the parent, at least this way. Note that the child must stay centered when the div moves.

TL;DR:

### How to center text in a div, and then still be able to move the div?

My html's body:

```
<div id="target">
    <p>Centered?</p>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
    div {
        outline: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #FF9F00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        
        /* how to center its child? */
    }
    p {  
        font-family: Arial;
    }
```

My javascript way of moving:

```
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    target.style.left = event.x + "px";
    target.style.top = event.y + "px";
});
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS so we can help you with modifying your code.

Comment: I'm back! I'll try to provide a minimal reproductible example in the minutes to come, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use flexbox?

```
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
}

<div><p>I want this paragraph to be at the center, but it's not.</p></div>
```

Comment: Ahah, how embarassing, it worked nearly first-try. Big thank you for the feedback. I'll still provide my code, and test other answers. I'll accept yours once I finished trying others.

Answer (score 2):

It works if parent `<div>` is `display: table-cell`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid green;;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>lorem ipsum bla bla blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I unfortunately can't get it to work with the rest of my code. Still upvoted though. That's my fault :/