# centering div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner level web designer. This question might have been asked, but I have refered that answers too but they have not helped.
My problem is I have a `div` called "header" and 3 divs inside this `div`. These are not aligning to the center in the parent `div`. I have tried many answers but they are not working.

Here is my code:

```
    #header {
    height: 176px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
       }
   #header div {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}

#logo {
    height: 156px;
    width: 218px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_03.jpg);


}

#tagline {
    width: 250px;


}
#badge {
    width: 300px;


}
```

here is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ebhar media</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<link href="style/homestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {

    min-width:1407px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="0px" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px">
<div id="base">
  <div id="header" align="center">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="tagline">YOUR SUCESS IS OUR SUCESS</div>
    <div id="badge">Content for  id "badge" Goes Here</div> 
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">Content for  id "navbar" Goes Here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to also show us your HTML for the header, plus what you would actually like to see.

Comment: One possible issue is that your `#header` lost its full width due to being `position: absolute;` - what happens if you give it `width: 100%?`

Comment: @KaraokeStu i have added the html codes

Comment: I just want to say that it's not good to have set `min-width: 1407px;` There are still people using resolution 1024*768 or 1376*768(13 inch notebooks)...

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 3):

remove the `position:absolute` from `#header` and remove `position:relative`, `float:left` from the `#header div`

```
#header {
    height: 176px;
    text-align: center;
/*    position: absolute;*/
}
#header div {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
/*    float: left;
    position: relative;*/
}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UYWqt/

Comment: Yeah this looks sensible. The `text-align: center;` and `margin: auto;` on the `#header div` is also redundant, i believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add some attribute on your div
try something like this

```
<div align="center">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
#header {
    height: 176px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header div { margin: auto; }

#logo {
    height: 156px;
    width: 218px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_03.jpg);
}

#tagline {
    width: 250px;
}
#badge {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you exactly need?

**http://jsfiddle.net/nJqfn/**

*Some remarks for future - don't use*

```
<body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="0px" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px">.
```

*It's better to include normalize.css or reset.css for cross-browser view.

That's*

```
<div id="header" align="center">
```

*not good too. Try to separate view and code.*