# How to center element inside of a div

Tags: css, margin, center

I want to center the content of `.SideBarFirst div` but don't know how to achieve this.

Can someone help me out with an solution which is not based on adding `padding` or `left/right` values to the element?

```css
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

.content {
    width:500px; 
    float: left;
}

.SideBarFirst {
    width:460px; 
    float: right;
}

.SideBarFirst div {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content">test</div>
    <div class="SideBarFirst">
        <div>not working for center</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My current code: http://jsfiddle.net/21sxvg4L/

Comment: first remove width and margin:0 auto in body

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center an element inside a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Comment: Yup display table and flex is not safe soloution for responsive website! 
Example: show a big image in display table this div scale and over 100%.

Comment: my question is why some time margin 0 auto inside off margin 0 auto working but sometimes not working ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this days problem solved with the display flex

```
.SideBarFirst {
    width:460px; 
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

by the way we can't apply margin or width to the body

Answer (score 1):

just remove this:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

use this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">test</div>
<div class="SideBarFirst">
    <div>not working for center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {width:500px; float : left;}

.SideBarFirst {width:460px; float : right;}

.SideBarFirst div {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

[See This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDwUG/)

Comment: i have seen this you just removed css from body

Comment: i already have seen this and i know what you changed when you wrote the code what was wrong with body width and margin auto

Comment: actually i don't know. its a strange behavior :|

Comment: ha ha he did nothing wrong in he jsut give width to body thats all and according to css rule its not good practice see my comment in question i already mentioned it there

Comment: why width in body make problem?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use %

```
.SideBarFirst div {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 50%; 
}
```

Or you can be more brute and try this:

```
.SideBarFirst div {
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 210px; 
}
```

Elastic layout will not work right with the this second code

Or this:

```
<div class="content">test</div>
<div class="SideBarFirst">
    <div align="center">not working for center</div>
</div>
```

Look this too: [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are floating the element to the left so that it will always appear on the left. If you wan to center it change your css to this:

```
.content {width:500px; float : left;}

.SideBarFirst {width:460px; float : right;}

.SideBarFirst div {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Also remove this:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```