# css center div inside container?

Tags: html, class, center

This HTML code works:

```
<div class="MyContainer" align="center">
    <div>THIS DIV IS CENTERED</div>
</div>
```

But I would like to do it at the css of the container, something like:

```
.MyContainer{
    align: center;
}
```

So all my containers will center the divs inside.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=center+div

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The CSS property for the **text align** is called [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) not `align` like in the inline DOM attribute.

---

If you want to **center a block element** (like `div`, `p`, `ul`, etc...) itself you need to set its width and set the horizontal margins to `auto`.

For example, the following code will make every div  inside an element with the `MyContainer` class 80% the size of its parent and center it in the middle of its container.

```
.MyContainer div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

### Code snippet

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}

.MyContainer div {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyContainer">
    <div>Inner DIVs are centered
        <div class="centered">Here the text is also centered</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't center the div. `text-align` influences the inline content of an element, a div is a block.

Comment: I understand from the OP that he wants to replace `align="center"` with a CSS definition.

Comment: text-align only centers the text but the div itself remains at the left of the container.

Comment: Yup !! that's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much !!

I just wonder why CSS 3 doesn't have an equivalent command for HTML "align"

Comment: Well this is the CSS way of doing this... Nevertheless this is an interesting question