# Center Div inside a main Div

Tags: html, alignment, center, css

i created a maze and i want to center an inside div
although i center it with margin: 0 auto; it won't work

(this div shows sad smily face when user enter the wall and lose)

```
#highlight_lose {
    width: 550px;
    height:550px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/28/

Comment: Do you mean center vertically?

Comment: When I have an absolute position I will sometimes use this trick to center it. Set it to left: 50%; and you can set margin-left: -275px; to offset half the width of your smiley. This will always keep your smiley center. :)

Comment: It looks like it is centered inside `#main`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FragJ/

Comment: @ExplosionPills  i nned the smily(#highlight_lose) will be in the center to the maze(#main)

Comment: @JoshC no cuz it's not centered:).  i nned the smily(#highlight_lose) will be in the center to the maze(#main)

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use absolute positioning you need to do it like this:

```
#highlight_lose {
    width: 550px;
    height:550px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -225px 0 0 -225px;
    display: none;

}
```

Edit: you also need to add `position:relative;` to the main div.  Here is an updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FragJ/2/

It looks off because you have other elements that aren't exactly centered.

**EDIT:** As I stated earlier, the smiley didn't look centered because your code is off.  The maze really should be inside a div itself.  However I was able to eyeball center it simply by playing with the margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/FragJ/4/

To achieve this you'll need to set your css like this:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#highlight_win {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
    margin: -180px 0 0 -180px;
}

#highlight_lose {
    width: 550px;
    height:550px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -180px 0 0 -180px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You also need to set the parent div to position: relative;

Comment: @JoshC thanks for your time but it's not centered in the fiddle example u gave me

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
            height: 600px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .inner {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

markup

```
<div class="outer">

        <div class="inner">

        </div>

    </div>
```

The idea is for fixed sized block elements, setting

```
margin:auto;
```

fixes horizontal centering

for vertical central alignment the child's `top = half the height of the parent - half the height of the child`