# How to vertically center two child DIVs inside of a parent DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

I am creating a site in bootstrap, and I want to know how to vertically center two child divs inside of a parent div. I know this is probably pretty simple, but I have tried everything and it will not work.

```
(http://codepen.io/cjhill02/pen/VLPERd)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: @DanielCompton I am sorry, I should have specified. I want to vertically align the child divs inside of their parent.

Comment: Vertical centering in 2015 still is an **incredible pain the ass**.

Comment: @connexo It really is!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center a div within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 0):

try margin:auto

```
* {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: auto
}
.col-md-6{
  margin: auto
}
```

for IE9 and IE10 put display:table to parent div and set attribute vallign="middle";display:table-cell to child element

vallign is a basic property supperted by old browsers as well as some new browsers

Comment: You know in these type of Conditions I preferably use Table in stead of display:table

Answer (score 0):

You can *always* do it with `display: flex;`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmrwcxo9/)

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.container div {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container > div {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 221.5433px;
}

.container > div + div {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 278.8431px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>centered</div>
    <div>centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok great! I was thinking about using display: flex, but I wasn't sure if that was the best way to go about doing it. Thanks

Comment: It doesnt have support for IE8 and below, but still, responsive web design and most modern techniques doesn't have support neither

Answer (score 0):

Do we know the height of the parent div? if so you can do like [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

```
.row {
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Please see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqWxZr) for result.

Comment: You do know what "vertical" means?