# Centering div inside div

Tags: html, css, center

http://jsfiddle.net/yr15y98e/

How would I go about centering the "CENTER"(yellow) div in the fiddle.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="leftdiv">left</div>
<div id="middlediv">middle</div>
<div id="rightdiv">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `margin-left: 25%;` in your `middlediv` class.

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `float:left` to your left div, then center by applying `text-align:center` to your container:

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align:center; /* ADD THIS */
}
#container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#rightdiv {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
#middlediv {   
    background-color: yellow;
}
#leftdiv {
    background-color: red;
    float:left;  /* ADD THIS */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yr15y98e/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#rightdiv {background-color: blue;}
#middlediv {background-color: yellow;}
#leftdiv {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftdiv">left</div>
    <div id="middlediv">middle</div>
    <div id="rightdiv">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of html like below:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="leftdiv">left</div>
<div id="rightdiv">right</div>
<div id="middlediv">middle</div>
</div>
```

And apply margin auto on middlediv like this:

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
}
#container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#rightdiv {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
#middlediv {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;/*center the div*/
}
#leftdiv {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```