# How to place a button in the middle of the page using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I would like to place a button in the middle of my page. What is the best way to center this button properly? steps by steps, please.

```
<button type="button">Welcome</button>
```

How can i center this to fit perfectly in the middle of my page? using the margins in CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Comment: <button type="button">Welcome</button>  How can i center this to fit perfectly in the middle of my page? using the margins in CSS?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978231/vertically-center-two-elements-within-a-div/31977476#31977476) may help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To centralize horizontally -Without using flexbox**

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/L8voe2t7/)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button">Welcome</button>
```

To make the button centralized, use the following CSS

```
button{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**To centralize horizontally and vertically -using flexbox**

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/L8voe2t7/1/)

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
button{
    display: flex;
    margin:0 auto;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center both vertically and horizontally using margins and positioning, you can do it like this:

```
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -50px; //half height and half width
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```