# Vertical align css not working html

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I have this page I´m doing. I want to vertical-align the text that says Od27, ver eventos(its a

, inside a div). The css is in the jsfiddle page.

I cant solve it. I saw other posts from other people and tried to solve it with that and nothing.

Here´s the code: http://jsfiddle.net/8c5d2pek/

```
<body>
<section class="home">
    <header>
    <div class="kvf_fotografia"></div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="nav-home">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-eventos">Eventos</li>
        <li class="nav-portfolio">Portfolio</li>
        <li class="nav-contacto">Contacto</li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
</header>
</section>
<section class="eventos">
    <h2>Eventos</h2>
    <ul>
    <li class="e1">
        <img src="img/eventos1.png">
        <div class="29er-desc">
        <p class="29er-p">29er</p>
        <p class="ver-eventos">ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e2">
        <img src="img/eventos2.png">
        <div class="420-desc">
        <p class="420-p">420</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e3">
        <img src="img/eventos3.png">
        <div class="cadet-desc">
        <p class="cadet-p">Cadet</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e4">
        <img src="img/eventos4.png">
        <div class="F18-desc">
        <p class="F18-p">F18</p>
        <p class="ver-eventos">ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e5">
        <img src="img/eventos5.png">
        <div class="J24-desc">
        <p class="J24-p">J24</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e6">
        <img src="img/eventos6.png">
        <div class="Laser-desc">
        <p class="Laser-p">Laser</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e7">
        <img src="img/eventos7.png">
        <div class="Od27-desc">
        <p class="Od27-p">Od27</p>
        <p class="ver-eventos">ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e8">
        <img src="img/eventos8.png">
        <div class="Paraolimpicos-desc">
        <p class="Paraolimpicos-p">Paraolimpicos</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="e9">
        <img src="img/eventos9.png">
        <div class="Optimist-desc">
        <p class="Optimist-p">Optimist</p>
        <p>ver eventos</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</section>
    <footer></footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Here are two simple methods for vertically centering divs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Comment: What's there to vertically align exactly - the first text inside that div itself?

Comment: the text that is inside that div.

Comment: Something like this then maybe, @Franco Marziano? http://jsfiddle.net/yc61ge2j/

Comment: Yes! I was going to post an image of what I want, because I have the psd file.

Comment: But, then I want to add some background colors to some of that divs, and it doesnt look so good.

Comment: Something like this, but for all the div. http://jsfiddle.net/yc61ge2j/ without the margin

Comment: I want to have the same height but in some of the divs(420, laser, f18 and paraolimpicos) i want a grey background without the margin, and vertically align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things of interest here... the `p` elements had default margin on them, giving extra vertical space between them so that got removed. Then some padding was added on the `div` itself to give vertical room. Because there's an image inside `li` as well, an extra line break would show some undesired margin beneath the image. That's what `line-height: 0` is for. It is then redefined for the `p` elements. Alternating background included (see comments, colors a bit different for demonstration) :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3q4j378/)

```
li {
line-height: 0;
}

li div {
padding: 25px 0;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) div {
background: blue;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) div {
background: grey;
}

li div p {
line-height: 20px;  
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: But I want the text to be under the image, vertically centered with a white background. And in the e2, e4, e6 and e8 divs the background to be grey.