# How to vertically align a div using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know this has been asked many times before but I simply can't follow the instructions on these other topics. Nothing seems to be working for me. Please check the screenshot to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish. Also, I added my code to this post.  Thanks!

```css
header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**
Using `position:relative;` and `top:50` and `transform: translateY(-50%)` you can get it centered, this is so good if you don't know the height of the element, like this:

*Support* : IE9+ and all other browsers, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/wd3ar5x5/)

```css
header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
  position:relative;
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

---

**Method 2**: using `.calc()` css function ,if you know the height of the element, like this:

*Support* : IE9+ and all other browsers, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/wd3ar5x5/1/)

```css
header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
  position:relative;
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  top:calc(50% - 27px); /* 50% parent height - 27px is half of 54px the height of .logo */
  left:0;
  background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

---

**Method 3:** if you know both elements height, you can manually subtract half the height of the `.logo` from half of the height of the parent div, so 90/2 - 54/2 = 18, like this:

*Support*: All browsers, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=position).

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/wd3ar5x5/2/)

```css
header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
  position:relative;
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  top:18px; /* 90/2 - 54/2 = 18  */
  left:0;
  background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks so much and all browsers will support this ?

Comment: Updated my answer with browser support

Answer (score 2):

it's worth noting that you could also accomplish this easily with `flexbox`, like so:

```
header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to vertically align an element, but in this case, where your `<div>` has an explicit height and sits inside a parent `<header>` which also has an explicit height, one of the simplest ways - supported by all browsers for the last decade and a half - is:

- Apply an equal `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

```css
header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

How to work out that the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` should each be `18px`?

(height of `<header>`) - (height of `.logo`) = `36px`

`36px` / 2 = `18px`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your logo class:

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of flexbox? It's great! Try this :

```
header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #ced0d8;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3 ways to solve this problem.

**Method 1:** Use `transform` property. ( [IE9+ supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) )

```css
header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

**Method 2:** Use `flex` property. ( [IE10+ supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) )

```css
header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

**Method 3:** Use `margin` property. ( [IE3+ supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Browser_compatibility) )

```css
header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
    margin-top: 18px;
    /* (90px (header height) - 54px (logo height))/2 = 18px; */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat trick using absolute positioning as shown below.

Since you specified a height and width for `.logo`, you can use `margin: auto` to center it both vertically and horizontally provided that `.logo` is absolutely positioned and all the offsets are set to zero.

This relies on CSS2 specifications and will work in quite a few browsers.

```css
header {
  width: 460px; /* narrow width for demo... */
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 209px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #ced0d8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just play around with the height and the padding of your header :

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 26px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 209px;
    height: 54px;
    margin : auto;
    background-color: #ced0d8;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
     <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/camtcupu/5/)!