# Central align of elements CSS without flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with getting text to appear in the middle of the screen (height-wise) on a webpage. The HTML of the site is:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
        <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>        
        <div class="home-container">
            <div class="home-row">
                <div class="some-other-class">
                    <p>text that should be in the middle</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is have the home-container element stretch all the way to the bottom of the page, and have the `text that should be in the middle` in the middle of it. My `css` looks like:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}


.home-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(139,0,0,0.4);
}

.home-row{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I understand that what I want to do is possible if I instead make `home-container` like so:

```
.home-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(139,0,0,0.4);
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

but this doesn't work on all browsers. What am I doing wrong with the `vertical-align` property? Id isn't really doing anything in my example...

Comment: to be able to use `vertical-align` you need to use `display:table` on big container ( .home-container) and `display:table-cell` on the `.home-row`

Comment: Use CSS table and positioning properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 21, accepted):

to use `vertical-align:middle` add `display:table-cell`on `.home-row` and `display:table` on `.home-container`

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/9rs2fayj/3/)** or snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}



.home-row {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.home-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: table;

}
```

```html
<div class="home-container">
  <div class="home-row">
    <div class="some-other-class">
      <p>text that should be in the middle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The **vertical-align** CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.*

read more here **[vertical align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)**

**EDIT 2020**
There's a better way to achieve the same result using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Check snippet below

Play around with `flexbox`. You can add it on other items not just the container

```css
.home-container {
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="home-container">
  <div class="home-row">
    <div class="some-other-class">
      <p>text that should be in the middle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works also on inline elements. for more info read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: The problem was I gave `vertical-align: middle;` to the container. I had to provide the style to the element I wanted to be aligned centrally within its container. (which means the child). Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
 <style>
    .home-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
        background-color: rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.4);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .some-other-class {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="home-container">
    <div class="some-other-class">
        <p>text that should be in the middle</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.home-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(139,0,0,0.4);
}

.home-row{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>example</title>
    <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div class="home-container">
      <div class="home-row">
        <div class="some-other-class">
          <p>text that should be in the middle</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```