# Center DIV vertically and horizontally in page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a DIV vertically and horizontally in a page:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {    
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

div.window {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="window">
    Sed blandit augue quis diam tristique fringilla. Morbi tortor leo, efficitur sit amet ultrices non, lacinia ut nunc. Donec ut odio a diam semper consequat quis in leo. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Somehow this is not vertically centered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: specify `.wrapper` height as `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: Your wrapper doesn’t have any height, _because_ you are positioning the child absolute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically center two elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978231/vertically-center-two-elements-within-a-div)

Comment: it's centred but relatively to its container with position:relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to center it, i will recommend using `display: flex;` instead of absolute positioning.

Something like:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.window {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="window">
    Sed blandit augue quis diam tristique fringilla. Morbi tortor leo, efficitur sit amet ultrices non, lacinia ut nunc. Donec ut odio a diam semper consequat quis in leo.
  </div>
</div>
```

Example codepen here: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/OJRJawN

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the `position: relative` in `wrapper` div. Without it, it works correctly.

```css
div.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.window {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="window">
    Sed blandit augue quis diam tristique fringilla. Morbi tortor leo, efficitur sit amet ultrices non, lacinia ut nunc. Donec ut odio a diam semper consequat quis in leo.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the wrapper should be surrounding the window, or else the red border won't render properly, this can't be the actual answer as wrapper needs a min height. If specified it would look proper.